# Ajax not executing asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0, long-polling

I have this piece of code

```
function getMesssages(id,c) {


        function waitForServerCall(id,c) {

            $.get(href("~/polling/" + id), function (response) {

                var r = c(response);
                if (r) {
                    return false;
                }

                waitForServerCall(id);
            });

        }

        waitForServerCall(id,c);

        $.post(href("~/batch/export/?batches=3344&pollid=" + id), function (response) {
            c(response);
            cancelCall = true;
        });
    }
```

The [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) inside the `waitForServerCall` method only get execute when the [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) recive the server response. Why?

This is the ajaxSettings:

```
accepts: Object
async: true
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: Object
converters: Object
flatOptions: Object
global: true
isLocal: false
jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: ()
processData: true
responseFields: Object
type: "GET"
url: "http://localhost:59161/"
xhr: In()
__proto__: Object
```

**Update.**
What i am doing is long polling, the post request is a long running process so i need to know some events that the server will trigger, the waitForServerCall method notify the client about the events that occured. But since the $.get method execute once the $.post response is recive, the notification process don't work.

Update 1:
Im using .NET 4.0 and Jquery 1.9.1.

Yes, the $.get request gets execute first but not response is recive until the $.post get the response. Once the $.post get the response, $.get execute correctly. But I'm expecting the $.get to get the server response even if the $.post has not get any response yet.

Comment: Please describe what behavior you are trying to achieve.  You are attempting to describe a problem, but don't really say how you want it to work.  Plus, it appears you have an error after you call `waitForServerCall(id);` because you aren't passing the second argument.

Comment: How do you know? Symptoms described don't make sense. Sounds more like  a case of code is doing what is written but not what you expected

Comment: Read the update please

Comment: Update doesn't outline any troubleshooting steps taken or what is happening with initial call of `waitForServerCall`

Comment: @charlietfl when waitForServerCall is call the first time, nothing happend. Not until the post recive the server response. Thats when the $.get inside the waitForServerCall function get execute. But since the response has already been recived, that means that the process has already finish. So I get no notification about some server events to the client

Comment: You may want to check that your server isn't preventing multiple AJAX requests from occurring at the same time. For example, ASP.NET blocks requests using the same session by default, so only one is allowed to process at a time.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior and how can i know that?

Comment: @Misters: First, it might help to share what server-side technology you're using. Secondly, try looking at the network traffic in your browser's dev tools to see if the get request is beginning prior to the post, and simply not completing until after the post completes.

Comment: I update the question. Take a look

Comment: what does `var r ` evaluate to before post completed? Also should throttle those get requests a bit using a timeout

Comment: @charlietfl if cancel the listening or not. I always return false for test.

Comment: if always return false there is nothing to make the subsequent polling call of $.get

Comment: for testing in the sence of never cancel the listing. In production code it will return true depending of the server event

Comment: sounds like a logic problem then. As soon as return false the get won't happen agan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85143/discussion-between-misters-and-charlietfl).

Comment: After alot test i figured out that the problem is in the server side. I tested the ajax request with jquery only and still getting the same sync call. I tested with angular only too but the sync call won't go asycn... Weird... I belived that each request creates its on thread...

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer of why.

All the credits goes to the author of this article:

http://josefottosson.se/c-sharp-mvc-concurrent-ajax-calls-blocks-server/